# The current thread must have a looper

Tags: android, view, java-threads, android-looper

Here I am trying to add a view over main_layout for a specific time duration, for that I write this

```
main_layout.addView(linearLayout)
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(Runnable {
        val timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                main_layout.removeView(imageView)
                timer.cancel()
            }
        }, 8000)
    })
```

but app gets crash with the error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!

kindly let me know, what else I have to do here.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are accessing the main_Layout from another thread. Try the Activity.runOnUiThread().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by using `HandleMessage()` method in handler.

```
mainHandler = object :Handler(){
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
                super.handleMessage(msg)
               if (msg!!.what ==1){
                   removeView()
               }
            }
        }

 private fun removedata() {
    main_layout.removeView(imageView)
}
```

also, to perform the desired operation, this method sends the required sets of instruction

```
mainHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1,5000)
```

so as you can see that to call remove(), it requires 1 to fullfil the condition and second parameter is the desired delay I wanted to set.